# Threads do not run (python3.6)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I found out that threading module in python 3.6 is not working properly.
problem is :

1. thread starts running before I call whatsoever_thread_name.start().
2. also, the code would not go to the next step from where I declare the first thread object in my code

Example :

```
import threading


def a():
    while(1):
        print(1)

def b():
    while(1):
        print(222)

t = threading.Thread(target = a())
v = threading.Thread(target = b())
```

result :
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
... infinitely

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the callback to `target`. Do *not* call the functions with `()`:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=a)
v = threading.Thread(target=b)
```

The threads will run these functions for you. The `()` means you are calling them yourself and attempting to assign the *return value* to `target`, but these functions don't return because they run forever.

Comment: What do you mean these function don't return because they run forever?

Comment: @user2259963 OP calls the function `target=a()`, so the function begins running before the thread is initialised. Since the function never ends, the threads are never initialised.